# How to hit a ball by bat with timing in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to create a cricket app in cocos2d, like stick cricket,
but I am confused about how the ball goes to different places when it is hit by a bat.

1. How is the ball going to different places when hit by a bat?
2. Are the pitch points randomly taken from some area or some selected points are randomly taken?
3. How to calculate the timing of bat, when it hits a ball?
4. Are the Batsman and bat different sprites or one sprite sheet animation?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to take a look at Box2D (included with cocos2d), start with this great tutorial:
[Intro to Box2D with Cocos2D Tutorial: Bouncing Balls](http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls)